# Enforce auto_now when using save(update_fields = […])

Tags: django, model-inheritance

Model definitions:

```
class Footprint(models.Model)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Stuff(Footprint):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
  some_other_field = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

In a `Stuff` object, I'd like to only update the `name` field, and leave all the other fields unchanged, except those defined in the associated `Footprint` object.

Fields in the `Footprint` object are correctly updated if I don't use `update_fields`:

```
s = Stuff.objects.get(pk = 1)
s.name = 'Alexander'
s.save()

s.date # is correctly set
```

But if I specify fields to update, the associated `Footprint` is not not even saved.

```
s = Stuff.objects.get(pk = 1)
s.name = 'Tim'
s.save(update_fields = ['name'])

s.date # unfortunately, remains unchanged!!
```

I have to use `update_fields` to avoid interferences between several scripts.

At the same time, I'd like to always keep track of the last modification, defined by the "Footprint" object (it contains the last modification date, as well as several other fields; their update is triggered by a custom `save()` method).

Is there a way to force a call to `Footprint.save()` even if `update_fields` doesn't contain any field from `Footprint`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was enough to simply rewrite the Footprint model definition like this:

```
class Footprint(models.Model)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.has_key('update_fields'):
      kwargs['update_fields'] = list(set(list(kwargs['update_fields']) + ['date']))

    return super(Footprint, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Of course, if you have more fields to update than just a `date` field, you just have to append them in the list.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of rewriting the `save()` method, the other possibility is to add all the fields with the `auto_now` option to the `update` parameter. Like this:

```
some_object.save(update_fields = ['updated_field', 'auto_now_date']
```

Comment: Guys really good solution here if you want one time change instead of overriding all the save method!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing your `.save()` method. Now, I now sure what it is that you want to do exactly, so I will leave you a template, since I believe wanting to have your own way of saving changes is indeed what do yo want.

In your class add this function definition:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do something here, whatever it is that you want
    return super(<YourClassName>, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This keep the features of the normal `save()` function unchanged and add your custom changes to the changes you want to make as well.

Comment: Thank you, it actually may be a way to do what I requested. I could add `p.footprint_ptr.save()` in the save method before calling `super()`, only if an `update_fields` argument exists. Since many models inherit from `Footprint`, is there a way to avoid redundant code? (only `<YourClassName>` will be different each time)

Comment: Well, you could turn save into a classmethod, but I don't have the kind of Python experience to help you if anything goes wrong. Try solving your problem via this, and give me an update if you were able to manage. Make sure you call save at the very end. So, if you want to change the `name` field for example, its something like `self.name = #whatever#`, then you go save, and the method signature for save is the same in all cases.

Comment: After further investigation, it appears that the `save` method of the Footprint object was already called (which is not so strange, because there is standard Python inheritance). So there is no need for `super(…).save(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce all `auto_now` fields of a Model to be updated when calling `self.save(update_fields=...)`, you can amend the behaviour of the `save` function by adding the following mixin to your model definition:

```py
class AutoNowMixin:
    """Model mixin that ensures auto_now fields are always updated."""
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        """Add all auto_now fields to update_fields to avoid broken db state."""
        if update_fields := kwargs.get("update_fields"):  # update_fields was specified
            update_fields = set(update_fields)
            for field in self._meta.get_fields():  # loop over all model fields
                if getattr(field, "auto_now", None):
                    update_fields.add(field.name)  # add auto_now fields if missing
            kwargs["update_fields"] = update_fields
        super().save(**kwargs)  # save with amended update_fields specified
```

Now add this mixin before the base class in your model definition:

```py
from django.db import models

class Footprint(AutoNowMixin, models.Model)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Stuff(Footprint):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
  some_other_field = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

...

s.save(update_fields=["name"])
s.date #  date is now updated because of its auto_now attr
```